# How to exlude a method with cane gem to avoid abc complexity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, canexecute

Hi i am working on a RoR project with [cane](https://github.com/square/cane) gem. I have a method inside an interactor. I am getting `Methods exceeded maximum allowed ABC complexity (1):`
For this method. I want to exclude this method to check complexity. So I tried:

```
Cane::RakeTask.new(:code_quality) do |cane|
  cane.abc_max = 15
  cane.no_style = true
  cane.no_doc = true
  cane.abc_exclude = %w(App::Interactors::StoreParserInteractor.find_date_time)
end
```

But still it throws the same error. Please help me how can I ignore ABC complexity only for this method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this integrated into your workflow, i.e. where and how exactly do you trigger it?

Comment: Inside the rake task code_quality.rake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](https://github.com/square/cane/blob/master/README.md#usage), I believe you'll need to go with:

```
cane.abc_exclude = %w(App::Interactors::StoreParserInteractor#find_date_time)
```

(notice the `#` sign where you had a `.`)

Comment: Thanks i will try